# Why does this number show up as a link?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, numbers

I posted the following number in an answer to a question, and surprisingly it is showing up as a link (as it does here)! 150103844.77

Out of curiosity, I clicked the link (something you should probably never do with suspicious links), and it says I need an app for it (which I did not download).  Is this a bug or something?

It still does it if I use HTTPS. I am using Windows 10, and the Edge browser.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's probably being detected as a phone number by whatever software you are using to browser Stack Exchange.

You mentioned you are using Edge on Windows 10. As it turns out, on a clean install of Windows 10, Edge does convert phone-number-like strings into a link, outside the DOM, and clicking on it opens up the "People" app to the contacts section.

[image: link]

<sup>(Tested with a clean Windows 10 VM I have handy.)</sup>

Don't worry, this is a software specific feature, it is not a problem with Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 7):

Guessing you have some sort of plug-in/add-on installed on your browser (or computer) that recognizes numbers as phone numbers that your computer can dial out to (skype does that, for example).

If it isn't a plug-in it might be injected by your ISP or some other agency sitting between you and Stack Exchange (browse over HTTPS to rule that out - if on HTTPS you don't see it - it is being injected).

This is **not** something Stack Exchange does.

Related: [Taming the automatic telephone number thing in the windows 10 edge browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718796/)

Comment: It still does it if I use HTTPS.  I am using Windows 10, and the Edge browser.

Comment: Skype is owned by Microsoft, who make Windows 10 and Edge... just saying... Did you install Skype?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31718796/taming-the-automatic-telephone-number-thing-in-the-windows-10-edge-browser

Comment: I don't have skype installed.  Perhaps that is the app it wants me to download?

Comment: Looks like something the Edge does, automatically, as the linked question in my previous comment claims.

Comment: I think the related link answers the question, thanks!