# Some related questions blank

Tags: bug

[image]

[On this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300900/conceptual-questions) the titles of several of the related questions [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252677/?rq=1) [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258685/?rq=1) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278380/?rq=1) are blank - the all end with ?rq1 unlike this question, which [shows](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254393/guidelines-limits-on-code-formatting-in-non-programming-stack-exchange-communi?rq=1) up

I can replicate this on firefox 55.0.3 on windows 10 version 1703, and vivaldi 1.10.867.38 (Not supported, I know, but second data point)

Comment: eh, his is more precise. Mine's better documented IMO. I guess I'll swing the way the community does?

Comment: No need to "document" this, it's not browser related. The server gives wrong results due to wrong SQL being used. A developer made a mistake, hope someone will notice the bug reports in 6-8 weeks. (Not sure since it's not critical bug, sites are all still useable.)